# Eclipse 3.4 / SWT - How to catch Mouse events during D&D operations?

Tags: java, eclipse, drag-and-drop, swt, jface

I've got a TreeViewer and would love to handle dropped files differently, based on what mouse Button the user presses for his drag operation. Is there any way to attach a listener to my Tree? It seems that events and filters don't get notified in case of drop events.

Comment: It is normal to use the `DND.DROP_COPY` and `DROP_MOVE` flags to control what to do. These are available in `getCurrentOperation()` if you use `org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ViewerDropAdapter`

Comment: I'd like to handle drops differently based on the mouse button used for the operation. Drop event handles don't provide you that sort of information.